# Action of Operator in lattice model

Tags: homework-and-exercises, operators, crystals, lattice-model

i'm dealing with a paper about square lattice in a magnetic field.
There are defined these operators:

$ T_{x}=\sum_{m,n}a^{\dagger}_{m+1,n}a_{m,n}e^{i\theta ^{x}_{m,n}} $ and $T_{x}=\sum_{m,n}a^{\dagger}_{m,n+1}a_{m,n}e^{i\theta ^{y}_{m,n}}$.

Now they calculate the action of $T_{x}$ and $T_{y}$ on a single-particle state $\psi_{i,j}=a^{\dagger}_{i,j}|0>$ like this:
$T_{x}T_{y}\psi_{i,j}=e^{i(\theta^{x}_{i,j+1}+\theta^{y}_{i,j})}\psi_{i+1,j+1}.   $

Please can anybody explain me in detail, why this is correct?  I think I have a thinking error.

Comment: $\uparrow$Which paper? Authors? Title? Page?

Comment: You have to Google: Square Lattice in magnetic field. Then you can download the PDF

Answer (score 0):

Here the $ a_{i,j}^\dagger$ is the creation operator, that creates a particle at the location $(x=i, y=j)$.

So the state $\psi_{i,j}$ represents a single particle at $(i,j)$.

Now, the $T_y$ operator makes all (because of the sum over $n, m$) the particles hop 1 unit in the $y$ direction, due to the $a_{m,n+1}^\dagger a_{m,n}$ term:

$a_{m,n}$ first destroys a particle at $(m,n)$ and $a_{m,n+1}^\dagger$ creates one at $(m,n+1)$.
Lastly, it rotates each of them by some $\theta_{m,n}^y$.

---

Only one term survives the sum over $n,m$ since there was a single particle in the initial state; the rest of terms are zero by definition because their respective lattice sites were empty - the $a_{m\neq i, n\neq j}$ operators try to annihilate the vacuum state.

In the end you apply the $T_x$ operator to the new state $e^{i\theta^y_{i,j}} \psi_{i, j+1}$ in a similar fashion.